# Как можно улучшить код

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, c++17

Имеется код класса для реализации словаря через `std::map`:

```
template<class Key, class Value>
class dictionary
{
public:
    virtual ~dictionary() = default;

    virtual const Value& get(const Key& key) const = 0;
    virtual void set(const Key& key, const Value& value) = 0;
    virtual bool is_set(const Key& key) const = 0;
};


template<class Key, class Value>
class Dictionary : public dictionary<Key, Value>
{
    std::map<Key, Value> _key;
public:
    Dictionary() = default;
    Dictionary(const Dictionary&) = delete;
    Dictionary& operator=(const Dictionary&) = delete;
    Dictionary& operator=(Dictionary&&) = delete;
    Dictionary(Dictionary&&) = delete;
    ~Dictionary() override = default;
public:
    const Value& get(const Key& key) const override
    {
        const auto i = _key.find(key);
        if (i == _key.end())
        {
            throw KeyNotFoundException<int>(key);
        }
        return this->_key.at(key);
    }
    void set(const Key& key, const Value& value) override
    {
        const auto i = _key.find(key);
        if (i != _key.end())
        {
            _key.at(key) = value;
        }
        else _key.emplace(key, value);
    }
    bool is_set(const Key& key) const override
    {
        const auto i = _key.find(key);
        return i == _key.end() ? false : true;
    }
};
```

Как можно улучшить код для `get` и `set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас достаточно странное использование метода `std::map.find()`. Вы пытаетесь найти элемент, и по полученному итератору уже судить найден ли он, а потом, если он есть, снова искать элемент методом `std::map.at()`.

Можно предложить три улучшения:

1. Кардинально не меняет код, вместо метода `find` и проверки итератора на конец можно использовать метод `contains`, но это если Вы захотите перейти на С++20, но опять же код будет не оптимален.
2. **Это решение предпочтительнее**. С помощью метода `find` вы получаете итератор, который указывает на элемент (если таковой есть), поэтому после проверки `if (i == _key.end())` Вы можете в возврате функции обратится к итератору и получить объект, на который он указывает и не искать повторно.
3. Можно использовать только метод `std::map.at()`.Работа с вариантом, когда нет элемента может быть такая: в этом же методе ловить исключение `std::out_of_range`, и пробрасывать своё, или же посылать это исключение дальше. Но тут важно помнить, что выбросить и принять исключение это относительно дорогая операция, поэтому 2 вариант и предпочтительнее.

Правда, зачем вы создаёте свой "словарь" на основе `std::map`, если `std::map` не только отлично с этим справляется, но и отлично сочетается с остальной частью библиотеки [STL для C++](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Answer (score 3):

- Вызовы `_key.at` не нужны, раз у вас под рукой есть итератор.
- [map::insert_or_assign](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) вставляет ключ или обновляет его значение:
- `KeyNotFoundException<int>` - `int` выглядит подозрительно.

```
    const Value& get(const Key& key) const override
    {
        const auto i = _key.find(key);
        if (i == _key.end())
        {
            throw KeyNotFoundException<Key>(key);
        }
        return i->second;
    }
    void set(const Key& key, const Value& value) override
    {
        _key.insert_or_assign(key, value);
    }
```